# Как сопоставить данные из двух массивов?

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы в параграфы добавлялся соответствующий текст. Например:
первый - arr[0],
второй - arr[1],
третий - arr[2],
четвёртый - arr[3],
пятый - arr[4]

Сейчас во всё добавляется последний элемент массива. Как сделать правильно?

```js
let arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"];

let description = document.querySelectorAll('.descr');
let res = Array.from(description);

res.map((item) => {
  arr.map((value) => {
    item.innerText = value;
  })
})
```

```html
<p class="descr"></p>
<p class="descr"></p>
<p class="descr"></p>
<p class="descr"></p>
<p class="descr"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если совпадает порядок элементов на странице и элементов массива, можно использовать совпадение их индексов и перебрать коллекцию элементов через метод `forEach()`, для этого даже не нужно превращать коллекцию в массив, у коллекции есть такой метод.

```js
let arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"];

let description = document.querySelectorAll('.descr');

description.forEach((element, index) => {
 element.textContent = arr[index];
});
```

```html
<p class="descr"></p>
<p class="descr"></p>
<p class="descr"></p>
<p class="descr"></p>
<p class="descr"></p>
```